# Question about Using MDAPackmol (packmol in python)

Tags: python, wrapper, bioinformatics, mdanalysis

I would like to use the python wrapper for packmol (MDAPackmol) for my research. In order to do so, I have tried to work with the example code and pdb files provided on [GitHub](https://github.com/MDAnalysis/MDAPackmol) so I can gain an understanding of the how to use the wrapper. However, when I run the code, I receive the following error message: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`.

Here is the full trace back:

[image: full trace back]

The error originates at `start.resname` being a zero-length string. It seems to be a problem with the resname having a number and a letter and thus is a problem with `Universe` (the object returned by `load_packmol_output`). Thus, there is a problem with the residues. I am now wondering if this is an error with how MDAnalysis is downloaded/installed or a missing dependency. Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question with full stacktrace of your error. I am unable to reproduce your ValueError. And just to make sure, you are using `['inside box 0. 0. 0. 40. 40. 40.']` as instruction (a `str` inside a `list`) instead of what you posted, right?

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Yes, that is what I am using. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really reproduce your error, but let's work backward from your stacktrace.

[image]

We're on line 184 in [mdapackmol.py](https://github.com/MDAnalysis/MDAPackmol/blob/master/mdapackmol/mdapackmol.py#L184). The part that fails is `int(start.resname[1:])`. If I run the example code, then `start.resname` is equal to `R0`, so `start.resname[1:]` is `'0'` and `int(start.resname[1:])` is `0`.

[image]

In your case, `start.resname` is probably something like `R`, so `start.resname[1:]` is `''` and `int(start.resname[1:])` then fails with a `ValueError`.

The rest of your stacktrace doesn't provide enough information to deduce why your `start.resname` doesn't have the desired format. But try to run your code in an editor with debugging support (like for example [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) like I did in the screenshot above), add ample breakpoints and try to step through your code and the MDAPackmolCode until you find where things go wrong

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try what you suggested. Glad the wrapper should work: this will really help my group out.